# My Images getting smaller in next page - DOMPDF

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, dompdf

[Here's the first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRgio.png)

[Here's the second page, the image is getting smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlyEp.png)

Created with DOMPDF and Laravel, the first page, my image is fine, but when the second page is getting smaller, i don't know why.. i've been trying to use div, but its still not working
i'm using table and here's my code

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$content['image2']}}" class="img kecil"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! $content['paragraph2'] !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I also using bootstrap, what should i do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: can u please show this live ?

Comment: i can't it still in local development, but you can see the pictures that i have uploaded

Comment: i can't help until i see live example

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: Fiddle or Live URL

Comment: Would help to at least see the CSS involved.